# How to not show a line break when blank?

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, line-breaks

In my Ruby app I'm using the following code in my view:

```
<% if post.image.present? %>
  <%= image_tag post.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
<% else %>
  <%= "" %>
<% end %>
```

If there's no image then it shows a blank which works fine.

The problem is that I do not want to show a line-break. Instead of `<%= "" %>`, is there something I can use to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this. Instead of a massive `if`/`else` statement, use the Ruby one-liner, and instead of an empty string, don't add anything if it's null:

```
<%= image_tag post.image_url(:thumb).to_s if post.image.present? %>
```

Note: If it's still adding a line-break, that's probaby something in your CSS. Nothing about this code should give you a line break.

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner code. I think I need to look into my CSS file or something

Comment: Likely there's some sort of margin-bottom. Use the element inspector in your browser.